# php not responding to ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, callback

I am new to jquery and php. I have designed a html login form. Point is I am clumsy at various coding techniques, and the following code is not working.

---

```
var inputs = $('#loginid, #pass').serialize();
$(".btn_loginsubmit").click(function() {
    var loginid = $("#loginid").val().trim();
    var pass = $("#pass").val().trim();

    if( (loginid != "") && (password != "")) {
        $.ajax({
            url:        '/inc/login.php',
            dataType:   'json',
            data:       inputs,
            type:       'post',
            success:    function(data) {
                $(".popup_login").fadeOut('fast');
                $(".alert_login").fadeIn('fast');
                $("#message_login").empty();
                $("#message_login").html(data);

                clear();
            }
        });
    else {
        $(".popup_login").fadeOut('fast');
        $(".alert_login").fadeIn('fast');
        $("#message_login").empty();
        $("#message_login").html("Enter details.");
    }
}
```

---

The php code is:

---

```
<?php
    include_once('phpfunctions.php');

    $rval = "";

    if(isset($_POST['loginid']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {

        $loginid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['loginid']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

        $qrymailchk = "SELECT * from master_db where user_mail='$loginid' AND user_pass='$pass'";
        $qryphonechk = "SELECT * from master_db where user_phone='$loginid' AND user_pass='$pass'";

        $resmailchk = mysqli_query($conn, $qrymailchk);
        $resphonechk = mysqli_query($conn, $qryphonechk);

        $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resmailchk, MYSQLI_BOTH);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resphonechk, MYSQLI_BOTH);

        if($row1 || $row2) {
            session_start();

            $_SESSION["uid"] = ($row1) ? $row1['user_code'] : $row2['user_code'];

            $_SESSION["un"] = ($row1) ? $row1['user_name'] : $row2['user_name'];
            $_SESSION["em"] = ($row1) ? $row1['user_mail'] : $row2['user_mail'];
            $_SESSION["ph"] = ($row1) ? $row1['user_phone'] : $row2['user_phone'];

            $words = explode(" ",$_SESSION["un"]);
            $_SESSION["fn"] = $words[0];
            ?>

            <script>alert("User logged in!");</script>

            <?php

            $rval = "Logged in as ".$_SESSION["fn"];
            echo $rval;

            $URL = "/services.php";
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";

            exit();
        }
        else{
            $rval = "Invalid LoginID Password combination!";
            echo $rval;
            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
    }   
?>
```

---

Here is the html code for the inputs:

---

```
<div class="inputfields_login">
    <a class="head_loginform">Login to Existing Account</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="input_id">
        <input type="text" name="loginid" id="loginid" placeholder="Login ID" <?php if (!empty($_POST['loginid'])) {echo "value=\"" . $_POST["loginid"] . "\"";} ?> >
    </div>
    <div class="input_pass">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password" >
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Now, I know the php code is working as I have used a $.post() call to this same code and it worked as I expected. There was a successful login and the page was redirected to the users' area.

However, it doesn't work in this case and the call is not made it seems. When I click the submit button, the page deos not do anything and the redirection does not work. Even the console log remains empty.

Please, I need some help regarding what is wrong in this code and some suggestions on how to make this work.

Comment: do you see post request unser Network tab when you post ?

Comment: have you checked the console log in your browser? i think that the call to the php file may not be getting to the correct place.

Comment: Also can you print you inputs variable on console

Comment: You can't serialize the data until user has filled it in. Serialize inside the event handler, not outside

Comment: `mysql_` doesn't work with `mysqli`. Hash your passwords.

Comment: @Yashveer Singh.. Yes and no, the Network tab shows a status 200 post to login, but inputs are not printed on the console.. I used none of these before..

Comment: @DebopamParua ???

Comment: @Chris.. No it is not printing the inputs..

Comment: @chris85.. yes, i removed the mysql_real_escape_string() part now.

Comment: @DebopamParua My comment is a note for things you need to fix, not an answer. You should update to parameterized queries.

Comment: @charlietfl.. giving it a try..

Comment: @chris85.. okay.. is there something like mysqli_real_escape_string().. is that what i need to use here?

Comment: That is only one problem...you have a lot of them. As for `mysqli_real_escape_string` paste that in a web search or in php manual

Comment: Yes, or parameterize the query. Parameterizing is the preferred practice. Also note the sytanx for `mysqli_escape_...` has changed form the `mysql_`s.

Comment: @chris85.. okay, I'll look into that.. but I don't think that is causing any trouble for the login part.. the thing is, the input fields are not inside a form, and I don't know how to serialize two inputs by id inside the $.ajax (data : ) thing.. What will be the syntax?

Comment: Yes, not your current issue. I ended up here from the PHP. This is a JS/jquery issue. I'd direct your comments to @charlietfl, he seemed more on point. My comments are for your user's security. With plain-text passwords and SQL injectable code you are asking for a problem.. Also don't put code in the comments, always update the question.

Comment: @chris85.. I have added the html code for the input fields in my question..

Comment: @chris85.. I am new here, and just learning to use this forum.. thanks for keeping your patience with me.. :)